# How to change year of date in mysql with dateformat and variables

Tags: mysql

I am building a function in MySQL and I need to change the year of a date. I want to use the `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SET teacherDate = (Select GebDatum from lehrer where Vorname = 'Erika');

SET eingabeDatum = DATE_FORMAT(eingabeDatum, year(teacherDate)-%m-%d);
```

I want to change the year of the "eingabeDatum" as follows: Month and day should be the same but the year should be the year of the "teacherDate".

Is it possible to use variables in the format part of `Date_Format`? If yes how is the syntax to use variables or functions like `YEAR()` in Date_Format.

Comment: What are you trying to change it to? Imagine Erika's `gebDatum` is 1970-01-01; what do you want it to be after the operation is over?

Comment: HI @GnutellCode - you could also use the MYSQL [DATE_ADD function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) or DATE_SUB functions?

Comment: Hi, thhanks for your replies. I want to change the "eingabeDatum". So Erikas Birthday is at the 1970-01-01. The "eingabeDatum" is the '2020-05-05". After my operation the "eingabeDatum" should have the same year as Erikas Birthday. So "1970-05-05"

Comment: Be aware... it is possible that you'll try to change a year in `XXXX-02-29` value to non-leap one which will cause an error. So `TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR, @needed_year - YEAR(@source_date), @source_date)` seems to be the most correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways that we can do this.

- We can use the functions `year()`, `month()` and `day()` to get the date parts and then use concat to construct the new date.
- When can use DateFormat to get the month and year and then use Date_Add to add the number of years from TeacherDate
- We can use concat to include Year(TeacherDate) in the formatting string in date_format
  All 3 methods have the same result.

> ```
> create table lehrer(
> Vorname varchar(10),
> teacherDate date,
> eingabeDatum date
> );
> insert into lehrer values
> ('Erika','2022-01-01','2010-04-05'),('Tobias','2022-01-01','2010-04-05'),('John','2022-01-01','2010-04-05');
> ```

> ```
> update lehrer
> set eingabeDatum = 
> concat(
>   year(teacherDate) ,'-',
>   month(eingabeDatum),'-',
>   day(eingabeDatum)
> )
> WHERE Vorname = 'Erika';
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE lehrer
> SET eingabeDatum = 
> DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(eingabeDatum, '0000-%m-%d'), INTERVAL YEAR(teacherDate) YEAR)
> WHERE Vorname = 'Tobias';
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE lehrer
> SET eingabeDatum = 
>     DATE_FORMAT(
>         eingabeDatum, 
>         concat(
>             YEAR(teacherDate),
>             '-%m-%d')
>         )
> WHERE Vorname = 'John';
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from lehrer;
> ```
>
> ```
> Vorname | teacherDate | eingabeDatum
> :------ | :---------- | :-----------
> Erika   | 2022-01-01  | 2022-04-05  
> Tobias  | 2022-01-01  | 2022-04-05  
> John    | 2022-01-01  | 2022-04-05
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8fe26b66103d04d1a8093b749d2cf362)*